# Compare the actual length of data in a column vs its declared size

Tags: sql-server

Is there a tool to compare the actual length of data in a column vs its declared size for SQL Server?

For example if I have a Name column declared at a varchar length of 100 but the longest name is only 25 I would want to tool to return those 2 numbers along with the table and column.

I am not on the cloud so that excludes products like DataDog. Most products I have researched analyze CPU, Memory utilization etc. and I haven't encountered something like this yet. Thanks!

Comment: you can Length or datalength option.  SELECT * from TABLE where len(name) = (SELECT max(len(name)) from table)

Comment: Yes, but I want it on the DB level for every table and col.

Answer (score 2):

The following query will get that information for all `n/varchar` columns in your database.

Note that `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` is for compatibility only and can be unreliable. And you need to use `QUOTENAME` to ensure names are quoted correctly.

```sql
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max);

SELECT @sql = STRING_AGG('
SELECT
  ' + QUOTENAME(c.name, '''') + ' AS ColumnName,
  MAX(LEN(' + QUOTENAME(c.name) + ')) AS RealMaxLength,
  ' + CAST(c.max_length AS nvarchar(max)) + ' AS DeclaredLength
FROM ' + QUOTENAME(s.name) + '.' + QUOTENAME(s.name),
  '
UNION ALL
'  )
FROM sys.tables t
JOIN sys.schemas s ON s.schema_id = t.schema_id
JOIN sys.columns c ON c.object_id = t.object_id
JOIN sys.types typ on typ.user_type_id = c.user_type_id
  AND typ.name IN ('varchar', 'nvarchar');

PRINT @sql;  -- your friend

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

You could improve the performance of this if you query all the columns for each table in one `SELECT` and unpivot the results.

Answer (score 0):

```
drop table if exists #temp
Create table #temp 
(
Table_Name varchar(50),
Column_Name varchar(50),
Character_Maximum_Declared_length varchar(50),
Max_Used_Len varchar(50),
CountValue varchar(50)
)
declare @SQL nvarchar(max)
set @SQL = ''
;with cols as (
select Table_Schema, Table_Name, Column_Name, Character_Maximum_length, Row_Number() over(partition by Table_Schema, Table_Name
order by ORDINAL_POSITION) as RowNum
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
where DATA_TYPE = 'varchar'  
)

select @SQL = @SQL + case when RowNum = 1 then '' else ' union all ' end
+ ' select ''' + Table_Name + ''' as Table_Name, ''' + Column_Name + ''' as Column_Name, ''' 
+ cast( Character_Maximum_length as varchar) + ''' as Character_Maximum_Declared_length, 
max(len( ' + quotename (Column_Name) + ' )) As Max_Used_Len,

count( '+ quotename (Column_Name) + ') as CountValue FROM ' + quotename (Table_Schema) + '.' + quotename (Table_Name)

from cols
--where Table_Name = 'Table' --print @SQL
insert into #temp
execute (@SQL)

select * , cast(Character_Maximum_Declared_length as int) - cast(Max_Used_Len as int) ColLengthDiscrepancy  from #temp
order by Table_Name, Column_Name
```

Comment: You are right. I will edit it.

Answer (score -1):

You can write a query that will generate other queries.  Run it then copy the columns out and execute that.

Here's a start - you can work out something more suited to your needs from here:

```
select 
  'select '''+i.TABLE_NAME+'.'+i.column_Name+
  ' has longest string of ''+ 
  cast(max(len('+i.COLUMN_NAME+')) as varchar)+
  '' from defined value of '+
  cast(i.CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH as varchar)+''' from '+i.TABLE_NAME
from 
  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS i
where 
 DATA_TYPE='varchar'
```